# PowerShell Variable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am looking up data and then want to add that to some kind of list which I can reference, for example if my data looked like this:

```
Name - John
Last Name - Doe
Age - 55
```

I would want to store that in a list and be able to do `foreach $member in $myList` and be able to print `$member.Name`

Hope that makes sense, not sure what the best way to do this is, would it be creating an object? or using a hashtable?

Comment: You are looking up data ... how?

Comment: Essentially the same comment applies here as I gave on the answer below. A hashtable is an object. TessellatingHecklers' question is important also because depending on how you get the data (if you used Import-CSV to get it from a CSV file for instance) then the data may very well already be in a collection of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PowerShell Hashtable for this:

```
$NameObject= @{
    'Name'='John'
    'LastName'='Doe'
    'Age'='55'
}
```

You can do this inside of a loop to add your data like so, to create a PowerShell Object.

```
 $NameObjectCollection = foreach($Object in $MyData)
 {
     #Add Data to Object
     [PSCustomObject] $NameObject= @{
         'Name'=$Object.Property1
         'LastName'=$Object.Property2
         'Age'=$Object.Property3
     }

     #Output object
     $NameObject

 }

 #Now you can loop over this data
 foreach($NameObject in $NameObjectCollection)
 {
     #Access the properties of the NameObject`
     $NameObject.Name
     $NameObject.LastName
     $NameObject.Age
 }
```